# Parse with Swift - User Queries

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im trying to query my Parse User database in order to create a friend request between two users.  The user inputs a user name that they want to add as a friend.  However, when I try to query the database, I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on the line where I am adding the condition. Not sure why Im getting this error, as its my understanding it has to do with trying to access memory already freed.  Anything that you can do to help would be very appreciated!

```
    var friendship = PFObject(className: "Friends")
    var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()

    findUser.whereKey("username",equalTo:username2) //program crashes here for some reason

    findUser.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (user2, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user2 == nil {
            println("Failure")
        } else {
            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            friendship["user1"] = PFUser.currentUser().objectId
            friendship["user2"] = user2.objectId
            friendship["pending"] = true
            friendship.save()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's username2 coming from? Could you post that code?

Comment: As the code is now, username2 is a hard coded string equal to a test user in the database.

Comment: I believe you need to get the PFUser object of user2 and the criteria should be PFUser2.username

Comment: I asked for specifics because it seems as if username2 may be deallocating before you get around to using it.

Comment: How would I go about getting PFUser2 though?  That is exactly what I am trying to do with this query.  This query should return the object that has a username key equal to whatever string is input.

Comment: Here is the code that generates username2.  

var username2:String = "testUser"

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the compiler and navigate the steps until you hit the crash so you can understand exactly at which point it crashes a troubleshoot further from there with the better understanding.

Also once it has crashed use LLDB print out `po ivar` to check if any of your ivars got instantiated and which ones are empty or execute dubious functions with `exp func`.

Comment: I have tried looking into the steps.  It appears to me that the function is completed completely.  It calls "libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release" and crashes on the last line which is a jmp call.

Im not sure what the ivars are, but I typed the command into lldb and I got a "use of unresolved identifier" error.

Comment: As another note, if I remove the whereKey;equalTo line and just get the first user in the user table, the code works fine.  It seems the issues comes from trying to add a condition to the query.

Answer (score 0):

So... It works today.  Not sure what happened.  Co-Developer and I reorganized frameworks and everything works fine now.  Thank you for your help everyone.  I appreciate the responses :)